# Swap index of an array with another using pointers, in C language

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Could anyone help me with my solution to this code? I have to trade the index of an array with another, using pointers.  This was the solution I created`

```
double *swap_double_array_ptr(double *pi, int pos1, int pos2) { 
         double *p = &pos1; 
         double *q = &pos2; 
         double aux=0;     
         aux = *(pi + p);    
         *(p + pi) = *(q+ pi);    
         *(q + pi) = aux;
```

}

The compiler says invalid operand. Can someone help me? I do not know any other solution. Please be gentle, I am new to pointers.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The operation of adding two pointers as in this expression statement

```
aux = *(pi + p); 
        ^^^^^^
```

is not defined in C.

And moreover the function returns nothing so its return type should be void.

It seems what you mean is the following

```
void swap_double_array_ptr( double *pi, int pos1, int pos2 ) 
{ 
         double aux = *(pi + pos1);     
         *(pi + pos1) = *(pi + pos2);    
         *(pi + pos2) = aux; 
}
```

Take into account that instead of the type `int` for the second and third parameters it is much better to use type `size_t` because in general the type `int` is not sufficient to store all possible indices of an array.

Comment: I checked the list of `undefined behavior` and I think the standard does not forbit to make addition of `pointer+floating_nr`.  Can you point where in ISO9899 it is marked that this is undefined ?  I suspect it will be converted in integer by default .

Comment: @alinsoar -- not exactly sure why you bring up addition of a pointer and a floating point number here, but this would be a constraint violation: [For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p2)

Comment: @alinsoar  See the section of the Standard 6.5.6 Additive operators

Comment: Where it is written that not accomplishing the constraints section would result in `undefined` behavior.  Can you point in ISO9899 this ?

Comment: Where did you read that invalidating the constraints is undefined behavior ?

Comment: @alinsoar I said nothing about the undefined behavior. I said that this operation is not defined in C. Reread the section of the Standard that I pointed out.

Comment: I do not want to keep contrary opinion with you.  I just want to understand if your formulation "is not defined" has something to do with ISO9899, and what precisely it has. How did you deduce, the violation of a constraint entailes non-defined ?

Comment: otherwise -- is it correct for a compiler to generate an undefined behavior -- for example to stop the analysis after a construction like `p[0.25]` , p being a pointer ?

Comment: @alinsoar One more I am not speaking about the undefined behavior. I am speaking about for which types the operation is defined. And in the quote there is written for which types the operation is defined.

Comment: Actually indeed, I checked -- any violation of any contraint is undefined behavior.

Comment: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/MSC40-C.+Do+not+violate+constraints

Comment: ``Violating a requirement specified using the word shall that appears within anotherkind of subclause causes undefined behavior`` -- quote from Derek Jones, `The New C Standard `.

Comment: Here it is : Chapter 4 -- Conformance: ``If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the behavior  is  undefined.   Undefined  behavior  is  otherwise  indicated  in  this  International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the omission of any explicit definitionof  behavior.   There  is  no  difference  in  emphasis  among  these  three;  they  all  describe‘‘behavior that is undefined’’.``

Comment: @alinsoar I do not understand why you are writing all this. From the very beginning it is clear that the operation is not defined for two pointers. So what is the problem?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I wrote because I did not know and I hoped that you can clarify.  I clarified after I googled for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap_double_array_ptr(double *pi, int pos1, int pos2) { 
         double aux;  
         aux = *(pi + pos1);    
         *(pos1 + pi) = *(pi+ pos2);    
         *(pos2 + pi) = aux; 
}
```

---

You were doing it all wrong by using the adress of the index variables.

You were *trying to add two pointers* which is ***not defined*** in c.

`aux = *(pi + p);` **`pi+p`** `-> Not allowed`

---

To summarize and provide some points:-

- Addition of two pointer variables not allowed.
- Subtraction of two pointer variables is allowed. (offset calculation)

As it returns nothing you need to make the function's return type void.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first thing is, `pointer addition` is not allowed in C. only pointer subtraction is allowed in c. you are trying to do `pi + p` which is invalid.